# ruby multiple loop sets but with limited rows per set

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9, nested-loops

Alrightie, so I'm building an CSV file this time with ruby.  The outer loop will run up to length of num_of_loops, but it runs for an entire set rather than up to the specified row.    I want to change the first column of a CSV file to a new name for each row.

If I do this:

```
class_days = %w[Wednesday Thursday Friday]

num_of_loops = (num_of_loops / class_days.size).ceil

num_of_loops.times { 
   ["Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"].each do |x|
      data[0] = x
      data[4] = classname()

      # Write all to file
      #
      csv << data
   end
}
```

Then the loop will run only 3 times for a 5 row request.

I'd like it to run the full 5 rows such that instead of stopping at Wed/Thurs/Fri it goes to Wed/Thurs/Fri/Wed/Thurs instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class_days = %w[Wednesday Thursday Friday]
num_of_loops.times do |i|
  data[0] = class_days[i % class_days.size]
  data[4] = classname
  csv << data
end
```

The interesting part is here:

```
  class_days[i % class_days.size]
```

We need an index into class_days that is between 0 and `class_days.size - 1`.  We can get that with the % (*modulo*) operator.  That operator yields the remainder after dividing `i` by `class_days.size`.  This table shows how it works:

```
i    i % 3
0      0
1      1
2      2
3      0
4      1
5      2
   ...
```

The other key part is that the `times` method yields indices starting with 0.

Comment: Thank you that's very interesting.  How does the i % class_days.size know to put the correct array value for that loop?  Can you give me a verbal explanation of the line?

Comment: wait I think that's modulus, so that's pretty cool...  why does the loop at 1 select the first in the array if class_days[0] would be the first array value?

Comment: ah, okay, times starts at 0 so not 1 for the loop.  Very sweet, I learned a lot ;)

Comment: @sf2k..because i in `num_of_loops.times do |i|` gives index..i.e. `5.times { |i| puts i }` will give 0 to 4 as output

Comment: thanks rubyprince i found that out with irb, then reloaded the thread to find your comment and that Wayne had updated his post.  I love this site.